# Form element wrong alignment, bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem with horizontal form in bootstrap3.

The alignment of label-button is fine as long as the label text is not too long.
The alignment of label-checkbox is fine as long as the checkbox has some text after it.

Working example:
[image]

```
 <form class="form-horizontal"> 
  <fieldset>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Download excel file.</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <div class="checkbox-inline">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Now the alignment goes haywire when I add a longer label and don't include any text behind the check box:

[image]

```
<form class="form-horizontal"> 
  <fieldset>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Download excel file bdhjfjsdhbfjshdb sjdhfhjsdhfhjgsdb</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <div class="checkbox-inline">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox">
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
```

You can clearly see the Sing In button going a bit higher than the label and the checkbox being a bit lower than the label.

I do not understand why this is happening and I need the second form to look normal. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: It's your markup. You no longer need the div class of `checkbox-inline` since you removed the "Remember me". Remove that div and `<label>` and add a class to column to handle the `padding-top: 7px;` that Bootstrap adds by default. Here's a fiddle example for you to review. http://jsfiddle.net/h2bztdtt/

Comment: See my updated response below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can clearly see the Sing In button going a bit higher than the label

That's how it works by default because of the top padding defined in the `<label>`. Notice how the button is also a little above the label in the original image post.

> http://getbootstrap.com/css/#checkboxes-and-radios

You're no longer inlining anything as you removed the `Remember me` text. So to align the elements correctly, use Bootstrap's `checkbox` class instead of `checkbox-inline`.

```
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here's a fiddle for you to review. http://jsfiddle.net/h2bztdtt/2/

Comment: Ok, thanks. This seems to work for bootstrap and the inline Problem. How about the Label-Button Problem? Also I eventually need to translate it to gwtbootstrap3, trying it out.

Comment: I revised my response to answer that question as well. That's expected behavior as you can see how the button is a little bit above in your original screen shot too.

Comment: Ok, thanks. This seems to work in gwtbootstrap3 too, although I got a new problem now. I have a Popover over the CheckBox and after using CheckBox instead of InlineCheckBox the Popover has shifted to the right too much and basically it's formatting just broke. Well, this is probably gwtbootstrap3's problem. Thanks again.

Comment: How do I reset the Label padding in bootstrap? Or do I need to write extra css code?

Comment: You can add a custom class to overwrite the top padding defined in Bootstrap. Like this http://jsfiddle.net/h2bztdtt/3/. See how I added `no-top-padding`. You can then reuse the class to each label or any element that you don't want the default padding to.

Comment: Thanks. This works in bootstrap but seems to have no effect in gwtbootstrap3

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are close. I was unable to recreate the checkbox being out of line so check any CSS you may have written. I was able to get everything to line up by putting a margin of 7px on the top of the button.

Comment: Thanks, this is also helpful.